# react-query cache data changed and re-render the app

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have data stored in a single folder. However, I wish to handle them separately within React Query. Furthermore, whenever there's a change in the cached data, I want it to trigger a corresponding update in the component's state, leading to a re-render of the application.

```
const { data: { bookmark: bookMark, reading: bookRead } = {}, error, isLoading } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['userData', userUID],
        queryFn: getUserData,
        staleTime: Infinity,
        enabled: !!userUID,
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData('bookmark', data.bookmark)
            queryClient.setQueryData('bookread', data.reading)
        },
    })
```

Currently start learning react-query from few days.
Any extra knowledge and functionality is highly acceptable and thanks in advance.

I want that when i manually changes cache data with queryClient.setQueryData it wil update the data state of react-query and make a re-render in the app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution but I don't know it's a good way or not

```
const { error, isLoading } = useQuery({
       queryKey: ['userData', userUID],
       queryFn: getUserData,
       staleTime: Infinity,
       enabled: !!userUID,
       onSuccess: (data) => {
           queryClient.setQueryData(['bookMark', userUID], data.bookMark)
           queryClient.setQueryData(['bookRead', userUID], data.bookRead)
       }
   })
   const { data: bookMark } = useQuery(['bookMark', userUID], {
       queryFn: () => queryClient.getQueryData(['bookMark', userUID]),
       enabled: false,
   });
   const { data: bookRead } = useQuery(['bookRead', userUID], {
       queryFn: () => queryClient.getQueryData(['bookRead', userUID]),
       enabled: false,
   });
```

Comment: You can directly access the data using ```const bookMark = queryClient.getQueryData(['bookMark', userUID])``` instead creating addition ```useQuery```.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a separate query if there is no corresponding resource to cache. You can always just call `useQuery` again of the `userData` and then just use the `bookMark` or `bookRead` property of it. You can also compose hooks and use the select option:

```
const useUserData = (userUID, select) => useQuery({
  queryKey: ['userData', userUID],
  queryFn: getUserData,
  staleTime: Infinity,
  enabled: !!userUID
})

const useBookMark = (userUUID) => useUserData(userUUID, data => data.bookMark)

const useBookRead = (userUUID) => useUserData(userUUID, data => data.useBookRead)
```

To address one of the comments:

> You can directly access the data using const bookMark = queryClient.getQueryData(['bookMark', userUID]) instead creating addition useQuery

This is wrong advice. Calling `queryClient.getQueryData` isn't reactive, so your component will not re-render on its own if data in the cache changes. To get reactivity, you need the `useQuery` hook, because that's what creates an observer.